# NinjectControllerFactory FileLoadException Error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ninject, hresult, fileloadexception

I tried create just example porject and I want use Ninject.I create NinjectControllerFactory.cs like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Ninject;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Moq;
using System.Linq;
using SportStore.Domain.Entities;
using SportStore.Domain.Abstract;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SportStore.Domain.Concrete;

namespace SportStore.WebUI.Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private IKernel ninjectKernel;

        public NinjectControllerFactory()
        {
            ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
            AddBindings();
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return controllerType == null
                ? null
                : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
        }

        private void AddBindings()
        {   
            ninjectKernel.Bind<IProductsRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();
        }

    }
}
```

and I create IProductRepository.cs like this

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SportStore.Domain.Entities;

namespace SportStore.Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface IProductsRepository
    {
        IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
    }
}
```

And the last one EFProductRepository like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SportStore.Domain.Abstract;
using SportStore.Domain.Entities;

namespace SportStore.Domain.Concrete
{
    public class EFProductRepository : IProductsRepository
    {
        private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

        public IQueryable<Product> Products
        {
            get { return context.Products; }
        }
    }
}
```

So when I run project I get this error

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 11:     public class EFProductRepository : IProductsRepository
>   Line 12:     { Line 13:         private EFDbContext context = new
>   EFDbContext(); Line 14:  Line 15:         public IQueryable
>   Products
>
> Source File: c:\Users\Ayyildiz\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\SportStore\SportStore.Domain\Concrete\EFProductRepository.cs
>   Line: 13
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' could not be loaded.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: User = Ayyildiz-PC\Ayyildiz LOG: DisplayName = EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Users/Ayyildiz/Documents/Visual Studio
>   2012/Projects/SportStore/SportStore.WebUI/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath =
>   C:\Users\Ayyildiz\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\SportStore\SportStore.WebUI\bin Calling assembly :
>   SportStore.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Ayyildiz\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\SportStore\SportStore.WebUI\web.config LOG: Using
>   host configuration file:
>   C:\Users\Ayyildiz\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config LOG: Using
>   machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Ayyildiz/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/85c19813/4c228712/EntityFramework.DLL. LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Ayyildiz/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files/root/85c19813/4c228712/EntityFramework/EntityFramework.DLL. LOG:
>   Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Users/Ayyildiz/Documents/Visual Studio
>   2012/Projects/SportStore/SportStore.WebUI/bin/EntityFramework.DLL.
>   WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major
>   Version ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040).
>   Probing terminated.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)]    SportStore.Domain.Concrete.EFProductRepository..ctor()
>   in c:\Users\Ayyildiz\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\SportStore\SportStore.Domain\Concrete\EFProductRepository.cs:13
>   DynamicInjectorc6bf6cff03594d109af1167280b346c5(Object[] ) +70
>   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)
>   in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:97
>   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:157
>   Ninject.<>c_*DisplayClass10.b*_c(IBinding binding) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:386
>   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +145
>
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4077101 
>   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.GetValue(Type service, IContext
>   parent) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs:197
>   Ninject.Planning.Targets.Target`1.ResolveWithin(IContext parent) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Planning\Targets\Target.cs:165
>   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.GetValue(IContext
>   context, ITarget target) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:114
>   Ninject.Activation.Providers.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_2(ITarget
>   target) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:96
>   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +66
>
>   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +216
>
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +77
>   Ninject.Activation.Providers.StandardProvider.Create(IContext context)
>   in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Providers\StandardProvider.cs:96
>   Ninject.Activation.Context.Resolve() in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Activation\Context.cs:157
>   Ninject.<>c_*DisplayClass10.b*_c(IBinding binding) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:386
>   System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +145
>
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source) +191
>   Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get(IResolutionRoot root, Type service,
>   IParameter[] parameters) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:151
>   SportStore.WebUI.Infrastructure.NinjectControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) in
>   c:\Users\Ayyildiz\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\SportStore\SportStore.WebUI\Infrastructure\NinjectControllerFactory.cs:29
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +226
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +326    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +177
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +88
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +50
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +301    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

I am using EntityFramework v6 and I am using MSSQL server 2008 r2. This error in NinjectControllerFactory.cs line this

```
return controllerType == null
                ? null
                : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
```

Anyone can help me please ? Thanks

Comment: Probably you have added reference to EF6 in your project and did not install it from Nuget. Make sure you have this in your webconfig:`<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and here's what I did to fix mine.  Maybe, this will help you fix yours.

The problem appears to be a versioning number issue of EntityFramework in your references (SportsStore.Domain and SportsStore.WebUI) and web.config in SportsStore.WebUI.

Check each EntityFramework reference and change each version to 6.0.0.0.  In SportsStore.WebUI, you won't be able to change it since it takes the entry from your web.config.  As a result, just remove the EntityFramework reference from SportsStore.WebUI.  Compile, and it should work.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

just remove references from all places and also check on different config file 
web.config, packges.config  from web ui 
and web.config, packges.confg from Domain

comment on all placed then add new reference.